# How can I limit the video duration when using the native android camera?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am building an app using the android native camera and I am also using the new API for activity results and contracts to call the camera, with this method:

```
ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo
```

I have to limit the videos's duration up to three minute long.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

By creating a child class of `ActivityResultcontracts.TakeVideo` and overriding the `createIntent` function.

```
public class customVideo extends ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo{
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(Context context, Uri input) {
        Intent intent = super.createIntent(context, input);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5); /* set duration limit */
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Use your custom class when create your `ActivityResultLauncher<Uri>`.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new customVideo(), /* use your custom class */
            new ActivityResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Bitmap result) {
                          /* code */
                    }
                }
        );
```

Then capture video just as before:

```
launcher.launch(uri);
```